# PdfPTable setting

Tags: java, itext

I have 3 code snippets:

```
float[] lfA_tables = {3, 44, 6, 44, 3};
lptbl_table = new PdfPTable(lfA_tables);            
lptbl_table.setWidthPercentage(100f);
```

and

```
float[] lfA_tables1 = {2, 40, 2};           
lptbl_table1 = new PdfPTable(lfA_tables1);          
lptbl_table1.setWidthPercentage(46);
```

and finally

```
float[] lfA_tables2 = {2, 40, 2};           
lptbl_table2 = new PdfPTable(lfA_tables2);          
lptbl_table2.setWidthPercentage(46);
```

I would like to know what the setting in the table array represent.

Comment: Have you tried the official documentation of iText?

Comment: I want to know why you did not find that information, because it is in the Javadoc and all common IDEs (IDEA, Eclipse, Netbeans,...) will show that in their "intellisense" when you hover over the keywords. I need more information from you, @cactus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constructor for `PdfPTable`:

> `PdfPTable(float[] relativeWidths)`
>
> Constructs a `PdfPTable` with the relative column widths.

And

> `setWidthPercentage(float widthPercentage)`
>
> Sets the width percentage that the table will occupy in the page.

Consult the iText documentation for all future requests.
http://itextsupport.com/apidocs/itext5/latest/

Comment: It looks like both table 1 and table 2 have three columns.                          
the  table has five columns ? late they will put both table 1 and table two into table

Comment: Nesting tables is always a bad idea. It's a layout mechanism that you can avoid, and it will always yield better performance if you avoid it.

Comment: Out of interest though, how come you didn't find the documentation? This might give us valuable feedback on what we can do to improve the visibility of the documentation.

Comment: It should be on document , may be I am new, I only find out this page and the code did not have any common

Comment: Table  
TableBorderEvent  
TableData  
TableRow  
TableRowElement  
TableStyleValues 
Class is used for storing style values of a table or cell.

Comment: one more stupid question in  float[] lfA_tables = {3, 44, 6, 44, 3}; the 3 is 3% or 3 pix?

Comment: It's neither. The values in that array indicate ratios. If you use {1,2,3} for example, you are essentially telling iText "I want the second column to be twice as wide as the first column, and the third column to be three times as big as the first column".

Comment: Also, if you're new to using iText, I would recommend using iText7. It's the latest version of iText. It features a lot of improvements, on fonts, tables, and various other iText features. And there's an extensive jump start tutorial that'll introduce you to all the iText building blocks.